# How to read a .CSV file with netlogo?

Tags: csv, netlogo

I'm starting in netlogo these days, so I've got some problems that I didn't find how to solve them.
    I have to read a huge .csv file, got this code on the web:

```
to openFile
file-open "testeCsv.csv"
set csv file-read-line
set csv word csv ","  ; add comma for loop termination 

let mylist []  ; list of values 
  while [not empty? csv] 
  [
    let $x position "," csv 
    let $item substring csv 0 $x  ; extract item 
    carefully [set $item read-from-string $item][] ; convert if number 
    set mylist lput $item mylist  ; append to list 
    set csv substring csv ($x + 1) length csv  ; remove item and comma 
    set fileList mylist
  ] 
  set fileList mylist
  show fileList
end
```

This file contains this line: "1;0;0;65;0;2;45;0;-0,018961934"
The output of this code is: "1 18961934"
Help :/

Comment: I know nothing about netlogo, but from its readable syntax, isn't your problem that your line is looking to tokenize the items in the csv through a comma (",") and your line has semicolons and commas as separators?
as in:
1;0...;-0,018961934

Comment: Hi! At first, I thought that it was the problem. I changed the separator between values to ',' and the decimal separator to '.', but didn't help.

Comment: Note that in current versions of NetLogo, it's much easier to use the CSV extension instead, http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code seems basically correct. I assume that csv and fileList are defined as global variables, otherwise the "set" commands on each will generate compile-time errors. We can also delete the reference to fileList in the `while` block since it is reset anyway once the `while` loop exits. Then, if you want to keep the semicolon as the separator we can make that change as well.  Altogether, we get:

```
globals [csv fileList]

to openFile
file-open "testeCsv.csv"
set csv file-read-line
set csv word csv ";"  ; add semicolon for loop termination 

let mylist []  ; list of values 
  while [not empty? csv] 
  [
    let $x position ";" csv 
    let $item substring csv 0 $x  ; extract item 
    carefully [set $item read-from-string $item][] ; convert if number 
    set mylist lput $item mylist  ; append to list 
    set csv substring csv ($x + 1) length csv  ; remove item and comma 
  ] 
  set fileList mylist
  show fileList
end
```

When I run this on the line in the CSV file you provide (after converting the decimal separator in the file from "," to ".") I get the result you seek, [1 0 0 65 0 2 45 0 -0.018961934].

Of course that reads only one line in the file.  I assume that you will want to loop through each line in the file, storing or using each line as it is read. The following stores each line in a list of lists.

```
globals[csv fileList]

to openFile
  file-open "testeCsv.csv"
  set fileList []

  while [not file-at-end?] [
    set csv file-read-line
    set csv word csv ";"  ; add comma for loop termination 

    let mylist []  ; list of values 
    while [not empty? csv] 
    [
      let $x position ";" csv 
      let $item substring csv 0 $x  ; extract item 
      carefully [set $item read-from-string $item][] ; convert if number 
      set mylist lput $item mylist  ; append to list 
      set csv substring csv ($x + 1) length csv  ; remove item and comma 
    ] 
    set fileList lput mylist fileList
  ]

  show fileList
  file-close
end
```

Comment: Note that in current versions of NetLogo, it's much easier to use the CSV extension instead, http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html

Answer (score 6):

First of all, CSV means *comma* separated values with a point decimal separator, not semi-colon separated values with a comma decimal separator.  See RFC 4180.  Although some have resisted this for nationalistic reasons, the scientific community needs to adopt the existing standard.  Agent-based modeling is part of the scientific community.

Now let's analyze what happen when you parse your file with this code.  It reads the line as a string into your `csv` variable.  It sets $x to 20 and extract the substring up to the comma.  The use of read-from-string treats "1;0;0;65;0;2;45;0;-0" as if it had been typed at the command center, so you just get the number `1`, since everything from the first semicolon onwards is a comment. The `1` is put into `mylist` and the `csv` variable is shortened to `018961934`. When this is read, you get `18961934` because NetLogo ignores the leading `0`.

This all happens because you do not have a real CSV file.  So you need to use a real CSV file if you want to use this code to parse it.