# How to read stock data in CSV file into netlogo?

Tags: csv, netlogo, stock

I want to load and read stock historical data into netlogo, and I found [how to read a .CSV file with netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096948/how-to-read-a-csv-file-with-netlogo) is very helpful.

However, to achieve what I need, I still need to go into each element list of `fileList` (see the link above), and extract each element of the element list and store them into different lists like `dates`, `openPrices`, `highPrices` and so on.

Could anyone show me the way how to achieve it? or point to some code examples can also be very helpful. I just started to learn netlogo, so there are a lot to catch up.

Thanks a lot!

stock historical data looks like this

> 2015/12/15, 12, 12.9, 11.99, 12.5, 10000
>
> 2015/12/16, 12.1, 13.9, 11.99, 12.8, 11000

```
globals[eachLine dates openPrices highPrices lowPrices closePrices volumes]

to openFile
  file-open "jqr.txt"
  set dates []
  set openPrices []
  set highPrices []
  set lowPrices []
  set closePrices []
  set volumes []

  set fileList []

  while [not file-at-end?] [
    set csv file-read-line
    set csv word csv ","  ; add comma for loop termination 

    let mylist []  ; list of values 
    while [not empty? csv] 
    [
      let $x position "," csv 
      let $item substring csv 0 $x  ; extract item 
      carefully [set $item read-from-string $item][] ; convert if number 
      set mylist lput $item mylist  ; append to list 
      set csv substring csv ($x + 1) length csv  ; remove item and comma 
    ] 
    set fileList lput mylist fileList
  ]

  ;; ??????
  foreach fileList 




  show fileList
  file-close
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out NetLogo's [csv extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html).

Comment: Thanks Alan, I will have a look.